# :: jQuery :: Split CSS value of inset and assign values to top, right, bottom and left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting CSS **inset** (absolute position) value to div dynamically like below.

```
inset: 8.01562% auto 3% 7.8047%
```

From above, I want to assign as CSS:

- first value (`8.01562%`) to `top`
- second value to `right`
- third value to `bottom`
- fourth value to `left`

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/19du8voz/9/)**

**Like below:**

```
top: 8.01562%,
right: auto,
bottom: 3%,
left: 7.8047%
```

```js
var __top = jQuery('.wrapper').css('inset')[0]
var __right = jQuery('.wrapper').css('inset')[1]
var __bottom = jQuery('.wrapper').css('inset')[2]
var __left = jQuery('.wrapper').css('inset')[3]

jQuery('.wrapper').css('inset', '')

jQuery('.wrapper').css('top', __top);
jQuery('.wrapper').css('right', __right);
jQuery('.wrapper').css('bottom', __bottom);
jQuery('.wrapper').css('left', __left);
```

```css
.wrapper{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="inset: 8.01562% auto 3% 7.8047%">My content</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you moving from `inset` (which is well supported, and less verbose) to using `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`? What's the problem you're facing? What's going wrong with your attempt? What are you trying to do (and, again: why)?

Comment: @David, While creating screen capture of the div, inset property is getting ignored... I cannot able to change the screen capture code as it is getting used for entire project

Comment: jQuery will not return the value of "inset" as an array of four values.

Comment: @Reddy *the inset property is being ignored* — what does that mean? Ignored by *what*?  Setting "inset" with four values is *exactly the same* as setting "top", "right", "bottom", and "left".

Comment: That looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You should re-formulate your question by asking why *"While creating screen capture of the div, inset property is getting ignored"* with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "inset" property is a *shorthand* property. To get the values set in your element with "inset", you have to use the underlying four properties:

```
var __top = jQuery('.wrapper').css('top');
var __right = jQuery('.wrapper').css('right');
var __bottom = jQuery('.wrapper').css('bottom');
var __left = jQuery('.wrapper').css('left');
```

You can get all of the properties at once if you like:

```
var props = jQuery('.wrapper').css(["top", "right", "bottom", "left"])
var __top = props.top;
var __right = props.right;
var __bottom = props.bottom;
var __left = props.left;
```

As per the jQuery documentation for `.css()`, retrieval of shorthand properties is not guaranteed. The underlying component properties should be retrieved, as in this answer.

Comment: Hi @Pointy, thanks for the reply. But I want to re-assign inset values as top, right, bottom and left.  var __values = $('.wrapper').css('inset')... I will get output as **8.01562% auto 3% 7.8047%**, i want this values to be assigned

Comment: Read the answer again. You cannot rely on being able to get the shorthand property "inset".  You should fetch the values of the individual properties ("top", "right", etc). Then you can reassign the values as in your original code. (I don't see the point of doing that, because setting "inset" as in your HTML will set each property anyway.)